# Templates for custom classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

It is a very common problem but I got stuck it!

I have a model class and I want to edit it in a view :

```
public class FormFillModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public List<FormFieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

I can edit string properties but I can not edit Fields property.

I created a editor template for it. under ~/shared/editortemplates/FormFieldsListModel.cshtml

```
@model List&lt;SoruCevapForm.Models.FormFieldModel&gt;

@foreach (var field in Model)
{
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label(field.Text)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => field.Val)
</div>
<br />
}
```

and finally...

```
<h2>FillForm</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Model.Title</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sector)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Sector)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        @Html.EditorFor( model => model.FieldsList.Fields, "FormFieldsListModel")

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

}
```

but when I post...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FillForm(int id, FormFillModel model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("UserPage");
    }
```

model.Fields property is empty.

**EDIT: Result Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>FillForm</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <a href="/Account/Logout">Logout</a>
    <br />


<h2>FillForm</h2>
<form action="/FormManage/FillForm/1" method="post">    <fieldset>
        <legend>TestForm2</legend>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label">
                        Title
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        TestForm2
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label">
                        Sector
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label">
                        Description
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        TestForm Description
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
    <label for="FieldsList_Fields__0__Name">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="FieldsList_Fields__0__Val" name="FieldsList.Fields.[0].Val" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<br /><div class="editor-label">
    <label for="FieldsList_Fields__1__Surname">Surname</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="FieldsList_Fields__1__Val" name="FieldsList.Fields.[1].Val" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<br /><div class="editor-label">
    <label for="FieldsList_Fields__2__Address">Address</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="FieldsList_Fields__2__Val" name="FieldsList.Fields.[2].Val" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<br />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<p>
    <a href="/FormManage/UserPage">Back</a>
</p>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an indexed access in your editortemplate while iterating your list:

```
@for (int i=0; i<Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Val)
    </div>
}
```

That will render names with an index for the input fields like `Fields[0].Val` and `Fields[1].Val` which is required for the modelbinder to bind the values to a list property.

**EDIT** 
I found an inconsistency in your view/model:

your model has a property calld `Fields`. But in your view you wrote model.**FieldsList**.Fields`:

```
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.FieldsList.Fields, "FormFieldsListModel")
```

How is this possible? Whats the exact viewmodel of your view?
That additional **FieldsList** renders the wrong fieldnames and so it can't bind to the **Fields** property of your model on post back.

Comment: but I am not using DefaultModelBinder. Interesting thing is, for HttpGet, editor templates are working. I mean, when I display form, this works. But when I post, model object is returning with empty properties.

Comment: @piedpiper I think you are using it - but nevertheless, i hadn't read your question to the end. I have completely rewritten my answer. Please check again.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML for one of the input elements for the Fields property

Comment: Ok, I editted my post. Please inspect. I suspect what is wrong but I cant find solution...

Comment: It looks ridiculous, I know, but FormFieldsListModel.cshtml accepts List<SoruCevapForm.Models.FormFieldModel> which has same type with model.FieldsList.Fields.

Comment: Its impossible, that using the viewmodel with the view you have shown in your question. Either it has a property `FieldsList.Fields` or your view won't work that way.